# Should an exclamation be accompanied by exclamation marks?

Tags: puntuación

I found this phrase in a book:

> ..., y el soldado exclamó:
>   "Ciertamente este hombre era Hijo de Dios."

Shouldn't it be like this?

> ..., y el soldado exclamó:
>   "¡Ciertamente este hombre era Hijo de Dios!"

Or are the exclamation marks taken for granted if it is explicitly stated that the person exclaimed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exclamation should definitely be accompanied by the exclamation marks, as you point out.

> ¡Aparta de ahí!
>
> ¡Cuidado!
>
> ¡Déjame en paz de una vez!

But [`Exclamar`](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=exclamar) has a wider meaning than "yelling, shouting or talking loud". One possible reason why there are no exclamation marks in the text there is because in that context "exclamó" is used as a synonym of "dijo", not "gritó". Realize that "exclamar" is

> Emitir palabras con fuerza o vehemencia para expresar la viveza de un afecto o para dar vigor y eficacia a lo que se dice.

So what the word "exclamar" in that context means not that the person is yelling or talking loud, but emphasizes the way something is said. So instead of a LOUD

> "¡Ciertamente este hombre era Hijo de Dios!"

it was a quiet

> "(Wow) Ciertamente este hombre era Hijo de Dios"

that conveys surprise and respect.